# What is the dtype in the return data from loc?

Tags: python, pandas

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[2, 3], [5, 6], [8, 9]],
     index=['cobra', 'viper', 'sidewinder'],
     columns=['max_speed', 'shield'])
df.loc['viper']
```

Produces this output

```
max_speed    5
shield       6
Name: viper, dtype: int64
```

dtype is 'Data Type', but what does it refer to? The index label, viper, isn't int64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`loc` is to access the row and column by its name, the `dtype` here refer to the dtype of the resulting `pd.Series` object

> ```
> Name : series name 
>
> dtype : series data type
> ```

```
df.loc['viper']
max_speed    5
shield       6
Name: viper, dtype: int64
```